# update all rows in table with different data php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have an application where investment profit should be calculated daily, which I intend to do using a cron job.

I calculate the profit by

```
$rate = $row_cron['rate'];
$amount = $row_cron['amount'];
$usernamex = $row_cron['Username'];
$check = $rate * $amount / 100;

$sql = "UPDATE users
         SET invest = invest + $check
         WHERE  status = 'member'";
```

To fetch my records I created a recordset of data using

```
mysql_select_db($database_emirate, $emirate);
$query_cron = "SELECT * FROM users";
$cron = mysql_query($query_cron, $emirate) or die(mysql_error());
$row_cron = mysql_fetch_assoc($cron);
$totalRows_cron = mysql_num_rows($cron);
```

The above code only returns the first record in my table.

I am trying to return all records in my table so as to calculate and update their records at the same time.

Comment: What is the question? Debug questions require a [mre]. [ask] [Help]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use pure SQL as you are updating the same table with calculated column. No loops are needed. Just run one query in PHP.

```sql
UPDATE `users`
SET invest = invest + (rate * amount / 100)
WHERE status = 'member'
```

Do note: SQL allows arithmetic calculations and some RDBMS's like MySQL even maintains [mathematical and statistical functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mathematical-functions.html).